# What is python __get__ method good for?

Tags: python

What can `__get__` achieve that can't be done with with a getter method on the owning object?

I can think of better separation of concerns but I guess there is more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's used for descriptors. They are kind of like Python's getters/setters, and properties, but better. It's how Python implements the Uniform Access Principle.
[Python Descriptors](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#creating-descritors)

Comment: "But better"? Properties are using the __get__ protocol, so it's not "kind of like", they *are*. ;)

Comment: No I mean properties in the Java sense, it's better because of UAP, so no more getProp(), setProp(blah) non-sense.

Answer (score 1):

Getter methods are ugly. It is much clearer to do:

```
obj.foobar
```

than

```
obj.get_foobar()
```

Secondly, it used to implement staticmethod, classmethod, and regular methods. All of these have slightly different behaviors and the `__get__` method is used to implement them.

Comment: But you can user property(...) or @property for pretty getters. I will take a look at the other uses. Thanks.

Comment: @reshefm, property is implemented using __get__. Its just a shortcut way of doing the same thing. __get__ basically allows you to make objects which act like property, but do something differently.